# Need regular expression to search inside string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need regular expression to search for comma if it appears more than once inside || and || and return the string between || and ||. For eg. consider this string:

```
$str = "http://www.test.com||abd-asd,asf,asfdsf[asf[s]asf,http://www.test1.com||asfsaf";
```

so after running regular expression on above string, it should return:

```
abd-asd,asf,asfdsf[asf[s]asf,http://www.test1.com
```

excluding || and ||. I have to use this in my PHP code.

Comment: Show what you've attempted, and we'll try to help fix it. Otherwise this is just "gimme the codez".

Comment: This question contradicts what your profile say: `I spend my spare time often in researching`

Comment: Regular expressions are better-suited for matching patterns, less so for searching.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357814/when-is-it-best-to-use-regular-expressions-over-basic-string-spliting-substrin

Comment: Though, the main drawback would be speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match(
    '/(?<=\|\|) # Assert starting position directly after ||<
    [^,|]*,     # Match any number of characters except , or |; then a ,
    [^,|]*,     # twice (so we have matched at least two commas)
    [^|]*       # Then match anything except | characters
    (?=\|\|)    # until we are right before ||
    /x', 
    $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: Never thought it was that easy. :) This really works out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Tim, can you modify it a bit to match if it appears more than once? This only show matched string in first || and ||, for subsequent appearance it ignores.

Comment: ok, I have changed preg_match to preg_match_all and it works.