# Detect terms in an expression using regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I want to detect all terms in a polynomial expression like

> x^2+3x-2

I want the string to be seperated into sub-strings at the '+' and '-'. In other words, I want to have the terms seperately. To simplify things, I add '+' or '-' at the start of the string if not already present to simplify things.

> +x^2+3x-2

Now, I need a regex which can detect all the terms seperately. I also need to keep in mind that there can be as many terms as possible.

I did try something like

> [+-]?(.+?)

but since I am new to regex, I don't think it is within my capability to make it work.

I need your help. Please note that in this case, the desired results are :

1. +x^2
2. +3x
3. -2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using the wrong technology here. You need to write a scanner and a parser. Regexes won't do it alone.

Answer (score 4):

A regular expression can do the limited job you state, as Joseph's answer shows.

But if you want to handle more complicated expressions then a regex wont cut it. Consider

```
x^(-2)+3x-2
```

or an unexpanded expression such as

```
x^2+3(x-2)-2
```

These require a parser: see [Regular Expression Vs. String Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905506/regular-expression-vs-string-parsing)

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
/[+-]?[^+-]+/g
```

Here's a quick explanation:

```
[+-]?   // Optionally find either a + or a -
[^+-]+  // Find as many non-plus-or-minus characters as possible
```

---

See it here in action: http://regex101.com/r/qA6nS0