# Regex for only the opening java doc comments

Tags: java, regex, javadoc

I'm trying to write a regex that matches java doc comments within java files and my code below doesn't seem to be working.

I'm specifically trying to match *only* the initial javadoc comments prior to the first occurrence of `public class blah {`

The code below finds the `JAVA_COMMENT_OPEN_TAG` without any issues but has trouble finding the `JAVA_COMMENT_CLOSE_TAG` tag:

```
public class JavaDocParser {

  private String JAVA_COMMENT_OPEN_TAG = "^/\\*\\**+";
  private String JAVA_COMMENT_CLOSE_TAG = "[.]+\\*{1}+/{1}$";
  private StringBuilder javaDocComment = new StringBuilder();

  public JavaDocParser(File javaFile) throws TestException {
    parseJavaDocHeader(javaFile); 
    printJavaDocComment();
  }

  private void parseJavaDocHeader(File javaFile) throws TestException {
    BufferedReader br = null;

    Pattern openPattern = Pattern.compile(JAVA_COMMENT_OPEN_TAG);
    Pattern closePattern = Pattern.compile(JAVA_COMMENT_CLOSE_TAG);

    boolean openTagFound = false;
    boolean closeTagFound = false;

    try {

      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(javaFile));

      String line;
      while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher openMatcher = openPattern.matcher(line);
        Matcher closeMatcher = closePattern.matcher(line);

        if(openMatcher.matches()) {
          System.out.println("OPEN TAG FOUND ON LINE: ====> " + line);
          openTagFound = true;
        }

        if(closeMatcher.matches()) {
          System.out.println("CLOSE TAG FOUND ON LINE: ====> " + line);
          closeTagFound = true;
        }

        if(openTagFound) {
          addToStringBuilder(line);
        } else if(closeTagFound) {
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      throw new TestException("The " + javaFile.getName() +" file provided could not be found.  Check the file and try again.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new TestException("A problem was encountered while reading the .java file");
        } finally {
      try {
            if(br != null) { br.close(); }
        } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
  }

  private void addToStringBuilder(String stringToAdd) {
    javaDocComment.append(stringToAdd + "\n");
  }

  public String getJavaDocComment() { return javaDocComment.toString(); }

  public void printJavaDocComment() { System.out.println(javaDocComment.toString()); }
}
```

Comment: @JAL thanks that question helps a lot.  I need to reword my question because I'm trying to do something a bit more specific.

Comment: Also in general regex is not a replacement for a parser.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905506/regular-expression-vs-string-parsing

Comment: @markspace thanks, that brings up a point I didn't give too much thought to.  I guess I considered a regex in the event that there are inconsistencies in the way people open and close their javadoc comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
private String JAVA_COMMENT_OPEN_TAG = "^/\*\*";
private String JAVA_COMMENT_CLOSE_TAG = ".*?\*+/$";
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fY0fR6/3)

Comment: Same result, finds the opening tag but not the end tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you include the beginning and end of line patterns `^` and `$`. But you could have whitespaces before or after the comments

Maybe it would be safer to use:

```
private String JAVA_COMMENT_OPEN_TAG = "^\\s*/\\*\\**+";
private String JAVA_COMMENT_CLOSE_TAG = "[.]+\\*{1}+/{1}\\s*$";
```

Comment: This only finds the opening tags.