# Using Regex to determine what kind of SQL statement a row is from a list?

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a large list of SQL commands such as

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE
INSERT .....
UPDATE .....
SELECT * FROM ....
```

etc. My goal is to parse this list into a set of results so that I can easily determine a good count of how many of these statements are SELECT statements, how many are UPDATES, etc.
so I would be looking at a result set such as

```
SELECT 2
INSERT 1
UPDATE 1
...
```

I figured I could do this with Regex, but I'm a bit lost other than simply looking at everything string and comparing against 'SELECT' as a prefix, but this can run into multiple issues. Is there any other way to format this using REGEX?

Comment: You can do `select
  count(case when s like 'SELECT%' then 1 end) as selects,
  count(case when s like 'UPDATE%' then 1 end) as updates,
  count(case when s like 'INSERT%' then 1 end) as insert
from t`.

Comment: To be clear, do you need an SQL solution? Or is this list just in a text file and you could use text-processing tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the SQL statements to a table and run them through a SQL query. If the SQL text is in a column called SQL_TEXT, you can get the SQL command type using this:

```
upper(regexp_substr(trim(regexp_replace(SQL_TEXT, '\\s', ' ')),
      '^([\\w\\-]+)')) as COMMAND_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some clean up to create a column that indicates the type of statement you have. The rest is just basic aggregation

```
with cte as
(select *, trim(lower(split_part(regexp_replace(col, '\\s', ' '),' ',1))) as statement
 from t)

select statement, count(*) as freq
from cte
group by statement;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a language and needs a parser to turn it from text into a structure. Regular expressions can only do part of the work (such as lexing).

[Regular Expression Vs. String Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905506/regular-expression-vs-string-parsing)

You will have to limit your ambition if you want to restrict yourself to using regular expressions.

Still you can get some distance if you so want. A quick search found this random example of tokenizing MySQL SQL statements using regex https://swanhart.livejournal.com/130191.html