# Java Regex for words including dash?

Tags: java, regex

I have an `input` and need to split and extract all `Strings` between `/`, using `regexp`.

I tried using: `\/\s*(\w+)`

This produces: `/pathvalue1`

Sample input:

`/pathvalue1/path-value-one
 /pathvalue2/path-value
 /pathvalue3/pathvaluethree`

Output that I need:

`pathvalue1
 path-value-one
 pathvalue2
 path-value
 pathvalue3
 pathvaluethree`

Any hints?
Much appreciated!

Comment: Why not simply split the string at the `/` using [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: I seems more "professional" work done with `regexp` and I want to impress. Yeah, I know, is not the best argument. I am trying to learn `regexp` matching.

Comment: As the others said but for the sake of answering your question: `\/\s*([^/]+)` ;-)

Comment: The "more professional" approach is to use the best tool for the job at hand. :)

Comment: `"/string1/string2".split("/");` ==> `["","string1","string2"]`, is that not enough?

Comment: `\w+` doesn't contain the dash char - so why not simply adding it? Or just as @Lothar suggested, use everything except the slash `/` as character range

Comment: As others have pointed out, this is not the best time to use regex. See: [When is it best to use regular expressions over basic string splitting/substring'ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357814/when-is-it-best-to-use-regular-expressions-over-basic-string-spliting-substrin) or [When should I not use regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553722/when-should-i-not-use-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

I would use split approach as Kushan pointed in his answer. However if you still want to use a regex, then you can use a regex like this:

```
([\w-]+)  or
([a-z-]+) with insensitive flag
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/mykGMs/1/)**

Java code

```
String text = "/pathvalue1/path-value-one\n" +
              "/pathvalue2/path-value\n" +
              "/pathvalue3/pathvaluethree";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([\\w-]+)").matcher(text);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**[IdeOne working demo](https://ideone.com/X51NJa)**

Output

```
pathvalue1
path-value-one
pathvalue2
path-value
pathvalue3
pathvaluethree
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the String split function to split your string into an array

```
String[] yourarray = Yourstring.split("/");
```

This should split your path and give you your seperated values.

You will find your hyphen seperated value in the array as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist using regex than you can use this `[^/\\s]+` with Pattern like this :

```
String[] strs = new String[]{"/pathvalue1/path-value-one",
    "/pathvalue2/path-value",
    "/pathvalue3/pathvaluethree"};
String regex = "[^/\\s]+";
for (String str : strs) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
pathvalue1
path-value-one
pathvalue2
path-value
pathvalue3
pathvaluethree
```

[**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZSGuNP/1)

---

You can solve your problem also using split just one point if you use split `str.split("/")` directly than you can get this results :

```
[, pathvalue1, path-value-one]
```

To make sure that you get the correct result, then replace the no usefull / or spaces in the start of the url so you can use :

```
String[] strs = new String[]{"/pathvalue1/path-value-one",
    "/pathvalue2/path-value",
    "/pathvalue3/pathvaluethree"};
for (String str : strs) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.replaceAll("^[/\\s]", "").split("/")));
}
```

Outputs

```
[pathvalue1, path-value-one]
[pathvalue2, path-value]
[pathvalue3, pathvaluethree]
```