# RegEx that will match accent characters and replace - with ' '

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all - with ' ' so that I will have

```
laos                           //  laos
new-caledonia                  //  new caledonia
saint-lucia                    //  saint lucia
st.-vincent-grenadines         //  st. vincent grenadines 
curaçao                        //  curaçao

saint-kitts-and-nevis          //  saint Kitts and nevis
falkland-islands               //  falkland islands
```

this RegEx match all but difficult to group-out the '-'
[My expression @ Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/xXZ2Ya/3/)

Comment: Use [.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with : ```/-/g```

Comment: I was able to match all with this code  ([A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ])+\.?((\-?)[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+)+ but I cant group out the -

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/xXZ2Ya/3/

Comment: So you just want to replace dash with space?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar Yeah

Comment: I just realized that @tomerpacific already mentioned this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tomerpacific mentioned in the comments, if you just want to replace dash with space then you can use replace on a string like this:

```
str.replace(/-/g, ' ')
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/xXZ2Ya/5)

```js
words = ['laos', //  laos
  'new-caledonia', //  new caledonia
  'saint-lucia', //  saint lucia
  'st.-vincent-grenadines', //  st. vincent grenadines 
  'curaçao', //  curaçao
  'saint-kitts-and-nevis', //  saint Kitts and nevis
  'falkland-islands' //  falkland islands
]   

words.forEach((word) => {
  console.log(word.replace(/-/g, ' '));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Regular Expression: `/(\b[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ.]+)/g` but performance-wise string parsing would be nicer. [When is it best to use Regular Expressions over basic string splitting / substring'ing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357814/when-is-it-best-to-use-regular-expressions-over-basic-string-splitting-substri)

Comment: You have replaced hyphen with space and that's a great and easy task, and your answer might have solved the question. I'm just trying to help if he want to use Regex and on what case, this regex would be grateful and useful if he wants to go for it in future tasks.

Comment: Ah okay. Also, you need to add the global flag. Your regex won't work otherwise :)

Comment: Yes! you are right, but / and also /g are available in regex101.com as he was trying to match on this website I've just included as it is so that there might not be any confusion. Thank you I'll update it.